# Updating UILabel while typing in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, string

```
 override func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

      label.text = textView.text 
      return true;
}
```

With this code, I seem to be a character behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shouldChangeTextInRange` will be called **before** the text field's text value is changed.

Try putting your code in [textViewDidChange](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618599-textviewdidchange) instead:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    label.text = textView.text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the previous textView's text. try:

```
 override func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

      label.text = text 
      return true;
}
```

as this method is called before the textView's new text is propagated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `NSString` `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)` to get typing text, like this

**Swift2**

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let originText = textView.text as NSString
    let replacingText = originText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text)

    label.text = replacingText
    return true
}
```

**Swift3**

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let originText = textView.text as NSString
    let replacingText = originText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)

    label.text = replacingText
    return true
}
```